# Ho do I stop and start autoupdating in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet in which a few sheets are very complex formulas which take a while to run.  I want to be able to update the support pages and only run the sheets with formulas when they have focus.  Is there anyway to do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the recalculation settings in Google Sheets only have effect for certain functions like NOW and RAND.

The alternative is to use scripts instead of formulas.

**References**
[Change locale, time zone, and recalculation settings - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en)

Related

- [Formulas always recalculating when refreshing/loading spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427160/1595451)