# Formulas always recalculating when refreshing/loading spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Anytime I refresh my spreadsheet tab, the formulas begin recalculating.
Not entirely sure why this is happening since the data has not changed, and the formulas have previously been loaded.

How do I stop this?

My spreadsheet settings are set to refresh on change and every hour.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you can stop a recalculation at this time. "On change", "On change and every minute", and "On change and every hour" seem to be the only options.

Here is a link from 2017:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/lTs0qvC6m8s;context-place=forum/docs

Comment: This is odd. If I open another spreadsheet with a formula, it doesn't recalculate anything and just shows the data it previously had. However, for another spreadsheet with data that also hasn't changed, the formula refreshes and begins calculating. Even though the final result is the same as before.