# Service Invoked Too Many Times error for Google Maps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a Script to call on google maps to give me a time duration between two locations.  I will use this up to five times per row as I'm trying to calculate the time for a route with up to five stops.  This is usually fine since I don't create more than 10 of these rows per day.  However, if I open up my google sheet, it will try to re compute all of these at once and result in an error telling me I've invoked the service too many times in the day.  Does anyone have any suggestions of either how to avoid this error, or to not have my spreadsheet need to recalculate these whenever I open it?
The Script was something that I just copied from here I think:
`/**
* Get Distance between 2 different addresses.
* @param start_address Address as string Ex. "300 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param end_address Address as string Ex. "900 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param return_type Return type as string Ex. "miles" or "kilometers" or "minutes" or "hours"
* @customfunction
*/

```
function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {

  // https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/
  // Nov 2017
  // improvements needed

  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }

}`
```

Is there a way to have my google sheet retain this calculated number?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808568/how-can-i-disable-automatic-recalculation-on-google-sheets

Comment: @Dijkgraaf , Thank you! That's a great idea to have them get toggled off by another cell!

Comment: @LukeVancleave Did you solve this issue? I was wondering if one could use lockService to solve this issue.

Comment: Use `CacheService`.

Comment: @Cooper my solution is working for me so far. What is lockService?